# How The Object Scope Get That update available and get it ready to be exposed on the view AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In AngularJS the data-binding work to expose immediate data to our View !!
this stuff's due of the object scope `which is the glue between the Logic Code` AND `The View`.
Also all we know that AngularJs support the tow-way-binding !!!
My Question Is :

```
How the $scope can know that there object binding was changed or not??
if there while condition inside scope for auto-change detect or what?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs

Comment: Thank you man ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Check angular.js file, we will get the code for ngBindDirective:

```
var ngBindDirective = ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    compile: function ngBindCompile(templateElement) {
      $compile.$$addBindingClass(templateElement);
      return function ngBindLink(scope, element, attr) {
        $compile.$$addBindingInfo(element, attr.ngBind);
        element = element[0];
        scope.$watch(attr.ngBind, function ngBindWatchAction(value) {
          element.textContent = isUndefined(value) ? '' : value;
        });
      };
    }
  };
}];
```

Note the last two line, it used watcher for attribute ngBind, for any change it apply to the element.